# Add sprite icon to a label . Is there a way to set width / height just for the sprite and a second w/h to the label?

Tags: css

This is probably a newbie question, but is it possible to add a sprite icon to a label with text?

ex:

```
<label class="icon">labeltext</label>

<style>
 .icon {
    width: 30px
    height: 30px;
    background: url("icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 }
</style>
```

When I set the width to 30px, the whole text isn't showing. Is there a way to have a sprite icon and a text inside a div / label / span ?

My real code looks more like this

```
<span class="additional-background">
    <span>text text text text</span>
</span>
```

If i set the width / height on the additonal-background where the sprite-icon is you can not see the text inside the text span. And if I set width on text span I can't manage to make a click-event on the "additional-background".

Additional
**I need to manage to have a click event on the icon, and not the text**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<label class="icon">labeltext</label>
```

CSS

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: url("icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but but what if I want to make a click-event on the icon and not the text.

Comment: Then you'll need markup along the lines of `<a href="foo"><img src="icon.png"/></a><span>text</span>`. Note that a `<label>` would be a bad choice here, because it's supposed to be tied to an input element, and provide a larger click area.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you have to set the background-position of images you are using as icon in class="additional-background" and give padding to the inside span where the text resides.

You can put the position of background image here itself like

e.g: `background: url("icon.png") no-repeat scroll 10px 10px transparent;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so ive amended my original answer as you state you need a hover state. So your image will need to be the normal state + hover state saved as one image then something like this:

HTML

```
<a class="clickme" href="yourpage.html"> Button text </a>
```

CSS

```
.clickme{
width:150px;
height:50px;
background:url ('image.jpg') no-repeat;
background-position: top; /* active state */
display:block;
}

.clickme:hover{
background-position:bottom; /* Moves the image on hover */
}
```

Im not sure why you need a label, id use just an 'a class'. The code above allows for a hover state for the button with doing anything to your text. You can additionally have a :focus for on click by adding a third variation to the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
<div id= background-image">
text text text text
</div>

#backround-image
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```